# How to query tables having manyTomany field in django

Tags: python, django

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pub_date = models.DateField()


class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
```

1. I actually need a single query that can get all "title" and "headline".
2. I need another query for where i can filter using either title or headline.
3. Lastly, I want to filter using both column e.g select all where title="Money" and publication="money talks"

I used this code but its giving me error.

```
Publication.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2016).select_related(publications)
```

Thank you

Comment: SO is not a query writing service. So, what have tried so far?

Comment: @KlausD i've been trying to read about it but am not getting it right. Am new to django.

Comment: Then add your failed attempts to your question!

Comment: @KlausD i have added one of the attempt.